# add comments forms which appears and dissapear on click

Tags: beamer

let consider this  how to build this on beamer knowing that we could change the text on it, and make them appear on click and disppear on click so that we could make many of them each time we talk about particular thing?

particularly am trying to make this as comments and to appear on the white part, but it is a figure it would be possible, and each click this would appear with a particular text on it ! [image: here is the figure]
excuse me am pretty new on latex & beamer..
thank you for your time and consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the cloud comment inside a scope where the bounding box is set as the size of the picture. In that way no extra space will be occupied by the cloud. (Actually in this example the scope is not needed, but with it, the figure can continue after the scope without taking affect of the cloud part.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt](Img){\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}};
    \draw<2->[line width=2pt,red](Img.north west) rectangle +(4,-2.5);
    \draw<3->[line width=2pt,black!20!green](Img.south west) rectangle ($(Img.south east) + (0,3.1)$);
    \onslide<4->{%
      \begin{scope}
        \useasboundingbox(Img.south west)--(Img.north east);
        \node[draw,cloud,anchor=south east,aspect=3,fill=blue,text=white] (Cloud) at ($(Img.north east)+(-0.5,0.5)$){2 variables};
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (Cloud.south west) to[bend right] ($(Img.center)+(2,1)$);
      \end{scope}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]