# including frame comments (as animation on beamer)

Tags: beamer

I would like to make  my frames each time one appear, it would be joined with a comment "frame", how to create such thing on beamer!

Here is a figure about what I hope do! Any proposition or maybe some links help me to do so.

[image: here is the figure]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use a minipage, place the blocks within, and then use a second one for the bubbles. Place a visibility command where you like it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use columns to place the blocks and notes beside each other - there you can also specify the overlay using `<1->` etc.

You should already know how to draw clouds from [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377564/36296), so I leave this part as exercise for you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}<1->{.6\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{title}
                content
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<1->{.3\textwidth}
            Note
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}<2->{.6\textwidth}
            \begin{alertblock}{title}
                content
            \end{alertblock}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<2->{.3\textwidth}
            Note
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}<3->{.6\textwidth}
            \begin{exampleblock}{title}
                content
            \end{exampleblock}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}<3->{.3\textwidth}
            Note
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]